# Getting a character from a 2d char array pointer that's a property on a struct pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, char

Okay, so this one is kind of weird and maybe there's a better way of solving this problem, but here's where I am.

I am writing a battleship game in C for my intro to CS class. I currently have a struct that looks like this:

```
typedef struct player {
    char *board[10][10];
    char *map[10][10];
    char *name;
    int kills;
    int deadShips;
    int scorePoints;
    int kdr;
    int hits;
    int misses;

}Player;
```

and 2 functions:

```
void printBoard(char board[10][10]) {
    char rowLetters[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};


    printf("    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  \n");

    // Rows
    for (int r = 0; r < NUMROWS; ++r) {
        printf(" %c ", rowLetters[r]);

        // Columns
        for (int c = 0; c < NUMCOLS; ++c) {
            printf(" %c ", board[r][c]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printChar(Player *p) {

    printBoard(*(p->board));

    printf("Choice: '%c'\n", *(p->board)[3][4]);

}
```

`printBoard` takes an array and prints it out. `printChar` is the part of my function that's failing. Right now, I just want to access one character of the board. After I can get that working, I can start performing checks to see if there's a ship at that location and adjust score, ship health, etc. accordingly.

I assumed that since p is a pointer to a struct and that struct has a pointer to an array on it, I could use 
`(*(*p->board))[row][col]` 
to get to the character I want. Especially since passing`*(p->board)` into `printBoard` works just fine. But getting one specific index isn't working. So basically, I need get to a frog that's on, a bump, that's on a log. Is there a syntax to help me with this? Or even a better way of structuring my program? I'm kind of new to pointers and If there's a better way I'm totally open to it.

Comment: You'll want to look at using 2D array emulation instead of literal 2D arrays when writing C code like this. You'll also want to avoid passing in large structures like `char board[10][10]` by value, but instead encapsulate those in some kind of `board` struct you can pass around by pointer instead. Above all else you'll want to avoid sprinkling "magic numbers" like `10` throughout your code and instead have clearly defined, meaningful constants like `BOARD_HEIGHT` and `BOARD_WIDTH` that can be changed once and that cleanly flows through the whole code-base.

Comment: Thanks! Changing those magic numbers to constants is on my to-do list. Now when you say 2D emulation vs literal 2D arrays, do you mean that there is some better structure for representing a 2D array than nested arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by your declaration of `char *board[10][10];`, and perhaps that is your problem.

This statement declares a 10x10 array of pointers to char, usually considered as a 10x10 array of string pointers. You need to allocate memory to the target of each of those 100 pointers, which I don't see you doing.

Perhaps what you want is `char [10][10]` which is a fixed array of 10x10 single character instances. That seems to be how you are using it, to my view.

@tadman suggests that the limitation of using a declared 2D array is that you can't make the code dynamic - you can't change the inner dimension, except perhaps use a smaller number, and ignore the higher indices.

If you declared a single dimensional array, or allocated it with malloc, and wrote your own code that said `cell=row*width+height` then you would have more flexibility.

To be honest though, these sorts of enhancements are just easier to write using C++ rather than C, and perhaps this is where you want to cut your cloth and limit the design.